# springboot api get way return 401 with keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have managed to setup keycloak server to authenticate my api I follow this [Youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/Fq85GschdLw?list=PLSVW22jAG8pDY3lXXEv1hKVIAlnJ9nDN_) I have been able to set realm, client, and user and able to authenticate via openid with username and password and return the token successful.But every time I open my api endpoint at first time every thing is ok am getting 200 response but after a while am getting 401 unauthorized even if I clear cookies and authenticate again am keep getting 4O1

Here is my openId Endpoint Configuration

```
{"issuer":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm","authorization_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth","token_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token","introspection_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect","userinfo_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo","end_session_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/logout","frontchannel_logout_session_supported":true,"frontchannel_logout_supported":true,"jwks_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs","check_session_iframe":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html","grant_types_supported":["authorization_code","implicit","refresh_token","password","client_credentials","urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code","urn:openid:params:grant-type:ciba"],"acr_values_supported":["0","1"],"response_types_supported":["code","none","id_token","token","id_token token","code id_token","code token","code id_token token"],"subject_types_supported":["public","pairwise"],"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":["PS384","ES384","RS384","HS256","HS512","ES256","RS256","HS384","ES512","PS256","PS512","RS512"],"id_token_encryption_alg_values_supported":["RSA-OAEP","RSA-OAEP-256","RSA1_5"],"id_token_encryption_enc_values_supported":["A256GCM","A192GCM","A128GCM","A128CBC-HS256","A192CBC-HS384","A256CBC-HS512"],"userinfo_signing_alg_values_supported":["PS384","ES384","RS384","HS256","HS512","ES256","RS256","HS384","ES512","PS256","PS512","RS512","none"],"userinfo_encryption_alg_values_supported":["RSA-OAEP","RSA-OAEP-256","RSA1_5"],"userinfo_encryption_enc_values_supported":["A256GCM","A192GCM","A128GCM","A128CBC-HS256","A192CBC-HS384","A256CBC-HS512"],"request_object_signing_alg_values_supported":["PS384","ES384","RS384","HS256","HS512","ES256","RS256","HS384","ES512","PS256","PS512","RS512","none"],"request_object_encryption_alg_values_supported":["RSA-OAEP","RSA-OAEP-256","RSA1_5"],"request_object_encryption_enc_values_supported":["A256GCM","A192GCM","A128GCM","A128CBC-HS256","A192CBC-HS384","A256CBC-HS512"],"response_modes_supported":["query","fragment","form_post","query.jwt","fragment.jwt","form_post.jwt","jwt"],"registration_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/clients-registrations/openid-connect","token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["private_key_jwt","client_secret_basic","client_secret_post","tls_client_auth","client_secret_jwt"],"token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported":["PS384","ES384","RS384","HS256","HS512","ES256","RS256","HS384","ES512","PS256","PS512","RS512"],"introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["private_key_jwt","client_secret_basic","client_secret_post","tls_client_auth","client_secret_jwt"],"introspection_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported":["PS384","ES384","RS384","HS256","HS512","ES256","RS256","HS384","ES512","PS256","PS512","RS512"],"authorization_signing_alg_values_supported":["PS384","ES384","RS384","HS256","HS512","ES256","RS256","HS384","ES512","PS256","PS512","RS512"],"authorization_encryption_alg_values_supported":["RSA-OAEP","RSA-OAEP-256","RSA1_5"],"authorization_encryption_enc_values_supported":["A256GCM","A192GCM","A128GCM","A128CBC-HS256","A192CBC-HS384","A256CBC-HS512"],"claims_supported":["aud","sub","iss","auth_time","name","given_name","family_name","preferred_username","email","acr"],"claim_types_supported":["normal"],"claims_parameter_supported":true,"scopes_supported":["openid","roles","phone","email","address","profile","acr","microprofile-jwt","offline_access","web-origins"],"request_parameter_supported":true,"request_uri_parameter_supported":true,"require_request_uri_registration":true,"code_challenge_methods_supported":["plain","S256"],"tls_client_certificate_bound_access_tokens":true,"revocation_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/revoke","revocation_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["private_key_jwt","client_secret_basic","client_secret_post","tls_client_auth","client_secret_jwt"],"revocation_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported":["PS384","ES384","RS384","HS256","HS512","ES256","RS256","HS384","ES512","PS256","PS512","RS512"],"backchannel_logout_supported":true,"backchannel_logout_session_supported":true,"device_authorization_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth/device","backchannel_token_delivery_modes_supported":["poll","ping"],"backchannel_authentication_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/ext/ciba/auth","backchannel_authentication_request_signing_alg_values_supported":["PS384","ES384","RS384","ES256","RS256","ES512","PS256","PS512","RS512"],"require_pushed_authorization_requests":false,"pushed_authorization_request_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/ext/par/request","mtls_endpoint_aliases":{"token_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token","revocation_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/revoke","introspection_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect","device_authorization_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth/device","registration_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/clients-registrations/openid-connect","userinfo_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo","pushed_authorization_request_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/ext/par/request","backchannel_authentication_endpoint":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/spring-cloud-client-realm/protocol/openid-connect/ext/ciba/auth"}}
```

Here is my authentication via Postman
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erWIQ.jpg)
which return the token but every time I use the token am getting 401 am stuck in this scenario any suggestion I would appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Due to the time expired token's 5 mins as default.
You can extend it by changing it in you "cloud-test" client' settings tab menu.

Click the Advanced Settings and change more longer time for
**Access Token Lifespan**
[image]

If you can copy access token text, you can measure it expired time
go [jwt.io](http://jwt.io), paste token into Encoded section and hover your mouse exp, you can see the expired data and time.
[image]